# Expression « Ça va que »

Tags: expressions, usage, étymologie, oral

J'utilise à l'oral et assez régulièrement l'expression « ça va que ».

Situation : J'ai pensé à prendre la carte d'identité de ma femme et pas elle.

> Ça va que j'ai pensé à te la prendre !

J'ai déjà entendu des présentateurs TV prononcer cette expression. De quelle origine est cette expression ? Est-elle correcte ? Est-elle si vilaine que cela à l'oral ?

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas cette expression. Dans ton exemple, ce serait l'équivalent de `Heureusement que j'ai pensé à te la prendre` ? A l'oreille, elle ne sonne en tout cas pas très bien.

Comment: C'est exactement pareil que 'Heureusement que...'

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression en France ou en Suisse. C'est peut-être un régionalisme? En tout cas, je rejoins @AGuif dans son commentaire, ça sonne pas terrible à l'oreille.

Comment: Ni en Belgique pour ma part, mais je suis frontalier.

Comment: Cette expression existe bien dans le langage parlé en France mais ne représente pas un bon français. Comme énoncé dans la question, c'est une expression "vilaine", familière donc pas forcément correcte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'entends assez régulièrement l'expression *Ça va que [...]*. Et effectivement, même à la télévision, qui décidément n'est pas une référence.

- *Ça va* est une familiarité [aux sens I.-B.-2. et 3. du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller)
- *Ça va que* est un emploi incorrect de cette familiarité en tant qu'expression signifiant *heureusement que*, ou encore *donc ça va*.

> Ça va que j'ai pensé à prendre ta carte

pourrait se réécrire, familièrement

> J'ai pensé à prendre ta carte, donc ça va.

ou mieux

> Heureusement que j'ai pensé à prendre ta carte.

*Heureusement que*, citée en commentaire sous la question, est quant à elle une expression correcte (cf. [sens II. de la définition du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/heureusement)).

Comment: Merci ! J'aurais bien aimé savoir d'où cette familiarité provient.

Comment: *Ça* est une abréviation familière de *cela*, et il y a quelques notes étymologiques en bas de cette page : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A7a . Quant à l'emploi intempestif que *que*, il se trouve dans plusieurs expressions fautives (ou plutôt dans nombre de "fautes notables", cf. l'affreux "à cause que" que l'on entend heureusement très rarement), mais je n'en trouve pas les racines.

Comment: @Shlublu _l'affreux "à cause que"_ et l'horrible "malgré que" !  :-)

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic Aïe ! Mes yeux saignent ! :)

Comment: Les journalistes s'expriment vraiment de plus en plus mal ! Je ne sais pas pour quelle raison ils font une école. "ça va" est acceptable, mais "ça va que..." n'est vraiment pas joli. Il est construit avec "ça va" comme expression figée. @Apaachee Concernant "ça va" ou "ça va que"?